# Pyspark get names of the column from a data frame of data type Boolean

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do something like this...
If I have 50 columns in my data frame and I want to get only the ones with boolean data type. How do I do that?

```
  for name,dtype in df.dtypes:
    if dtype is 'Boolean':
      print(name)
```

This is printing blank

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`. `==` tests for equality, whereas `=` is for variable assignments

Comment: that worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select function

```
df.select('column_name').show()
```

If column's data type is string and you want to select it as an integer, you can cast it to integer

```
df.select(df.column_name.cast('integer')).show()
```

Or you can create a temp table and use SQL

```
df.registerTempTable('table1')
spark.sql('select column_name from table1').show()
```

UPDATED

if you want to call all columns which is integer data types only, you can use something like below

```
>>> data = sc.parallelize([(1,'a',3.5,8,True)])
>>> cols = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5']
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data,cols)
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+----+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|  c5|
+---+---+---+---+----+
|  1|  a|3.5|  8|true|
+---+---+---+---+----+
>>> df.dtypes
[('c1', 'bigint'), ('c2', 'string'), ('c3', 'double'), ('c4', 'bigint'), ('c5', 'boolean')]
>>> [i[0] for i in df.dtypes if 'int' in i[1]]
['c1', 'c4']
>>> df.select([i[0] for i in df.dtypes if 'int' in i[1]]).show()
+---+---+
| c1| c4|
+---+---+
|  1|  8|
+---+---+
```

Comment: I have several variables of data types like string, int but I only want to select the ones with int as data type

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm